# How to bind events to dynamically created JQuery DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm having trouble referencing an object from within the plugin I'm attempting to make.

The plugin is assosciated with a div container.

When the dom is ready it loads in startup defaults - creates its own div with id's it knows and an un ordered list. I can add list items and they work correctly using `$this.append(..)`. However I want to add a feature where a click on an individual list item does something.. for now alert will suffice.

Normally I would be able to do:

```
$("#myId").click(function(){...
```

How would i add such functionality to a plugin?

I want that action set by the plugin itself, so clicking on list items created by the plugin are already attached to some functionality which I have written into the jquery plugin.

Comment: Since you are developing the plugin, can you have it accept click functionality for the children as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you could store the new tab in a variable:

```
var newTab = $("<li id='tab#" + o.tabCount + "' myTabPane='" + 
    o.tabId + o.tabCount + "' class='tab'><h3>Tab " + o.tabCount
    + "</h3></li>");
$('#' + o.tabListId).append(newTab);
newTab.click(function() {
    var paneId = '#' + $(this).attr('myTabPane');
    $(paneId).siblings().hide();
    $(paneId).show();
});
```

Link to [working example at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2yuM/13/).

By the way, your original script had the second `'` in the wrong place:

```
$("<li id='tab#'" + o.tabCount + " class='tab'><h3>Tab "
              ^^^
```

Comment: Cheers! but still the same problem, if you take a look at the comment I placed @VulgarBinary you can find a link to the code.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for this, it seems more inline with what Im after. Just off the top of my head though If i have a ton of 'tabs' and want to keep track of them, i.e clicking on one tab is not the same as another and I want to change the content pane beneath the tabs to go back and forth depending on which tabs have been clicked. Knowing this would it alter your answer in anyway? Thanks.

Comment: @Juli: You could give each tab an attribute with the id of the corresponding pane.  Example added

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Ive marked your answer as correct. Thanks alot. Whilst on the subject of this, the number of tabs I have in the div if the length of them is greater than the width of the browser screen they run onto multiple lines. Do you have any suggestions on dealing with this?

Comment: @Julio: No idea, in fact I'd be interested in the answer to that.  Maybe a new question?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to reference them after doing the append by tag name not by ID.

```
$(this).find("li").click(function(){  /* do work */});
```

If you absolutely have to reference it by ID you can do:

```
$(this).find("li").each(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   /* do work */
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however im still having the same problem. i've moved the code over to js fiddle to show what i mean. http://jsfiddle.net/d_a_n/q2yuM/. I basically want to be able to only perform a click action on a 'tab' and get that tabs details. However the tabs are generated dynamically.

Comment: This process still pulls tabs added dynamically.  You would just put it after your appends.  To address your comment from the above comment (just for other passer-bys) you would add data="#pannelID" to your LI append.  JQuery can evaluate dynamically added html as it would static html.